# How to find angle at centroid of triangle by its edge lengths?

Tags: trigonometry, triangles, angle, centroid

I need to write a program that takes length of a triangle's edges and calculates the angle $\angle APB$ ($P$ is the centroid of the triangle). Thanks for any help or clue.

Comment: Angles can be conveniently determined by dot product of vectors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
PA^2=\frac {2b^2+2c^2-a^2}9,\quad PB^2=\frac {2a^2+2c^2-b^2}9\\
\implies \cos(\angle APB)=\frac {PA^2+PB^2-c^2}{2\cdot PA \cdot PB}
=\frac {a^2+b^2-5c^2}{2\sqrt{(2b^2+2c^2-a^2)(2a^2+2c^2-b^2)}}.
$$

Comment: Great, how did you get it? checked with a=b=c=1, $\angle APB=120^o$.

Comment: I still remember the law of cosines. :)

Comment: That is what i need thanks.

Comment: @BaranSAHİN You're welcome!